# Correctly configuring a dashboard layout using a grid-container with css

Tags: html, css, python-3.x

I have started learning css so that I can change the layout of the dashboards I build with [Dash](https://dash.plot.ly/). The following code runs simple dashboard that I practice on:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id = 'url', refresh = False),
    html.Div(id = 'page-content'),
])

def display_links():
    links = html.Div([
        dcc.Link('Page 1', href = '/page1'),
        dcc.Link('Page 2', href = '/page2')
    ])
    return links

page1 = html.Div([
    html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.Link('Go to page 1', href= '/page1')
        ], className = 'grid-item1'),
        html.Div([
            dcc.Link('Go to page 2', href= '/page2')
        ], className = 'grid-item2'),
        dcc.Graph(
            id = 'graph',
            figure = {
                'data':[
                    {'x': [1,2,3], 'y': [4,2,3]}
                ],
                'layout': {
                    'title': 'Graph'
                }
            }
        )
        ], className = 'grid-item3'),
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Dropdown 1'),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown-menu1')
        ], className = 'grid-item4'),
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Dropdown 2'),
            dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown-menu2')
        ], className = 'grid-item5'),
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Slider 1'),
            dcc.Slider(
                id = 'slider1',
                min=0,
                max=4,
                value=0,
                marks={
                    0: {'label': '3 days'},
                    1: {'label': '1 week'},
                    2: {'label': '2 weeks'},
                    3: {'label': '1 month'},
                    4: {'label': '2 months'}
                }
            )
        ], className = 'grid-item6'),
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Radio items 1'),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id = 'radio-item1',
                options = [
                    {'label': '1', 'value': 1},
                    {'label': '2', 'value': 2}
                ],
                value = 1
            )
        ], className = 'grid-item7')
    ], className = 'grid-container')
])

page2 = html.Div([
    html.H1('Page 2'),
    display_links()
])

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('page-content','children'),
              [dash.dependencies.Input('url','pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/':
        return page1
    if pathname == '/page1':
        return page1
    if pathname == '/page2':
        return page2
    else:
        return display_links()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

After going through [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid_item.asp), I wrote the following css stylesheet:

```
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.grid-item2 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.grid-item3 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 5;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.grid-item4 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.grid-item5 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.grid-item6 {
    grid-column: 4;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.grid-item7 {
    grid-column: 5;
    grid-row: 3;
}
```

When I run the dashboard I looks like this:

[image]

Although this looks fine, it is not what I intended. I want the two links located to the left of the graph, and I want the four filter options spaced evenly below the graph. Something like this:

```
Link 1  |        Graph                Graph        |
Link 2  |        Graph                Graph        |
        | Filter 1 | Filter 2 | Filter 3 | Filter 4|
```

I have based my css on this [piece of code](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid_item) and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I'm using a grid with 5 columns and 3 rows; link 1 is assigned to column 1 and row 1; link 2 is assigned to column 1 and row 2; the graph is assigned to columns 2 up to and including column 5 and rows 1 and 2; the four filters are assigned to columns 2,3,4, and 5 of row 3.

I have two questions regarding this layout:

**Question 1:** What am I doing wrong in the css/python code and how do I fix it so that the dashboard has the desired layout?

**Question 2:** Is this the correct/accepted way of managing the layout of a dashboard? If not; how *should* I design the dashboard layout?